# JavaFX event Callback back to parent unit

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I have a JavaFX program in which I am looking to assign an event handler for a button but I want the event to trigger an action in a parent unit.

I have a `GridPane` as my main pane.
When I start my program, I have another Group of shapes (Called a Block) embedded in this gridpane at a fixed location (0,0).
As part of my Block, I have a Triangle button called `DownArrow`.  My Plan is that when this button is pressed, the Doc controller will place a new Block beneath the one where the triangle was pressed.

I am looking at using the `DownArrow.setOnMouseClicked` event handler and map this back to the routine in the Controller to Add a new Block... However, I need some sort of info callback to let the controller know what Block was pressed.

I'm Stumped.

I was looking at maybe creating a custom event handler that I can pass more parameters but it seems clumsy - is there something else I should be doing?

[How to pass paremeter with an event in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372236/how-to-pass-paremeter-with-an-event-in-javafx)

See Code Below in full:

```
package editorscratchpad;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author a_curley
 */
public class EditorScratchPad extends Application {

    HBox mainPanel;
    VBox flowChart;
    GridPane flowchartGrid;
    VBox controlPanel;
    Integer stepCount;
    TextField descData;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        descData = new TextField();
        stepCount = 0;

        btn.setText("Add Step");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            buttonClicked(event);
        });

        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        mainPanel = new HBox(20);
        //mainPanel.setPrefWidth(400);
        controlPanel = new VBox(5);
        controlPanel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        flowChart = new VBox();
        flowChart.setPrefWidth(600);
        flowChart.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        flowchartGrid = new GridPane();
        flowchartGrid.setPrefWidth(600);
        flowchartGrid.setHgap(10);
        flowchartGrid.setVgap(10);
        flowchartGrid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));

        //sp.setContent(flowChart);
        sp.setContent(flowchartGrid);

        controlPanel.getChildren().add(btn);
        controlPanel.getChildren().add(descData);
        mainPanel.getChildren().add(sp);
        mainPanel.getChildren().add(controlPanel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPanel, 800, 500);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Flow chart");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        //Integer Step = stepCount*10;        
        //Integer Step = (flowChart.getChildren().size()+1)*10;
        Integer Step = (flowchartGrid.getChildren().size() + 1);
        String stateDesc = descData.getText();
        if (stateDesc.length() < 3) {
            stateDesc = "State " + Step.toString();
        }

        blockComponent newBlock = new blockComponent("S" + Integer.toString(Step * 10), stateDesc, Step); //<<<< Create the Block.
        //flowChart.getChildren().add(newBlock.getComponent());
        flowchartGrid.add(newBlock.getComponent(), 0, Step);
        System.out.println("Added S" + Integer.toString(Step * 10));
        stepCount++;
    }

    public void addNewBlock(ActionEvent event) {
        Integer Step = (flowchartGrid.getChildren().size() + 1);
        String stateDesc = "Step " + Integer.toString(Step * 10);
    }

    /**
     * Subclass representing a Block Graphics only.
     */
    public class blockComponent {

        String Name;
        String Desc;
        Integer StateNo;
        Integer XLoc;
        Integer YLoc;
        Integer blockHeight;
        Integer blockWidth;
        Integer stLabRad;

        public blockComponent(String newName, String newDesc, Integer newSt) {
            Name = newName;
            Desc = newDesc;
            StateNo = newSt;
            XLoc = 0;
            YLoc = 0;
            blockHeight = 60;
            blockWidth = 120;
            stLabRad = 10;
        }

        public blockComponent(String newName, String newDesc, Integer newSt, Integer xCoOrd, Integer yCoOrd) {
            this(newName, newDesc, newSt);
            XLoc = xCoOrd;
            YLoc = yCoOrd;
        }

        public Group getComponent() {
            Group thisGroup = new Group();
            // Define Rectangle
            Rectangle Block = new Rectangle();
            Block.setY(stLabRad);
            Block.setX(stLabRad);
            Block.setHeight(blockHeight);
            Block.setWidth(blockWidth);
            Block.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            Block.setStrokeWidth(2);
            Block.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);

            // Define state label
            Circle stLab = new Circle();
            stLab.setCenterX(stLabRad);
            stLab.setCenterY(stLabRad);
            stLab.setRadius(stLabRad);
            stLab.setStroke(Color.PALEGREEN);
            stLab.setFill(Color.PALEGREEN);

            // Define State No.
            Label stNo = new Label();
            stNo.setFont(Font.font("Impact"));
            stNo.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
            stNo.setLayoutX(0);
            stNo.setLayoutY(0);
            stNo.setText(StateNo.toString());

            // Define the description
            Label stD = new Label();
            stD.setFont(Font.font("Impact"));
            stD.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
            stD.setLayoutX(15);
            stD.setLayoutY(15);
            stD.setText(Desc.toString());

            //---- Three Triangles for drawing. ----
            // Down Arrow
            Polygon downArrow = new Polygon();
            downArrow.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                //X                                         //Y
                (blockWidth.doubleValue() / 2) + stLabRad, (blockHeight.doubleValue()),
                ((blockWidth.doubleValue() / 2) + 10) + stLabRad, (blockHeight.doubleValue() - 10),
                ((blockWidth.doubleValue() / 2) - 10) + stLabRad, (blockHeight.doubleValue() - 10)
//                70.0,60.0,
//                60.0,50.0,
//                80.0,50.0
            });
            downArrow.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            downArrow.setStrokeWidth(1);
            downArrow.setFill(Color.LIGHTCYAN);
            downArrow.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                    downArrow.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                    downArrow.setFill(Color.LIGHTCYAN);
                }
            });
            downArrow.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                    downArrow.setStroke(Color.WHITESMOKE);
                    downArrow.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
                }
            });

            // try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372236/how-to-pass-paremeter-with-an-event-in-javafx
            //add all components to the group to display
            thisGroup.getChildren().add(Block);
            thisGroup.getChildren().add(stD);
            thisGroup.getChildren().add(stLab);
            thisGroup.getChildren().add(stNo);
            thisGroup.getChildren().add(downArrow);
            return thisGroup;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `event.getSource()` and retrieve info about it, like `((Button) event.getSource()).getText()`?

Comment: [mcve] - strip it down to the barest minimum to demonstrate what you are after (no need for going fancy with fonts ans similar unrelated stuff). And stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: all that said: why do you need the event at all? just expose api to do what you need and let the button's action use that api ..

Comment: I'll try getSource thank you 0009lah

Comment: I'm not sure what angle to approach @kleopatra so I canont provide a simple example.  To give an example of what the blocks produce I included the whole routine.  I appreciate it might be too much but its small enough so I thought it was more helpful to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the correct approach I was looking for but @0009laH response above for getSource() was the best that worked for me.